# How to define a bottom value for a formula's return in a cell based in another cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I've been looking for it for a long time, but only now I'm not allowed to create a vba function for this and it would be better not to use an "If" since the formula is already getting more complex than I would like to use for this project.

I have a cell that is the result of a way too big chain of "IF"s (extremely simplified below for the sake of shortness of the sample):

```
    =IF(
        Aux_2!B2=1;
            IF(
                E43=0;
                    MIN(PG_Inicial!E49;PG_Inicial!E51);
                    MIN(PG_Inicial!E43;PG_Inicial!E49;PG_Inicial!E51));
            IF(
                E43=0;
                    MIN(PG_Inicial!E49;PG_Inicial!E51;PG_Inicial!E53);
                    MIN(PG_Inicial!E43;PG_Inicial!E49;PG_Inicial!E51;PG_Inicial!E53)))
```

But now any return it should give must be greater than or equal to E40.

Is there a built-in function to do it in excel-2007? Or the only way to do it is to use another "IF"?

Editing:
As Gary suggested, you don't need to have a "bottom" limitation, you can use the "MAX" function.

It would look like :

```
    =MAX(E40; TheBigFormula)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

=MIN(E40,*YourBigFormula*)

Comment: if the bigformula is smaller than E40 your suggestion will result in the bigformula value and it should be the opposite, but your suggestion made me think that the MAX should work... thanks